# Bitcoin checkout on website - do i need to download the blockchain?

Tags: nodes, payment-processors

Based on a previous setup, what I was thinking about doing is coding my web application to send JSON RPC calls to a bitcoin node to see if a transaction has been received. Previously I have done this by running the bitcoind on the web server, but my server isn't big enough for that now. Is it possible to just send the JSON RPC to any other bitcoin node? Is there some way of finding those nodes without just always using the same, hardcoded node?

Comment: Thank you but it looks like that only addresses the issues of creating addresses, which i understand doesn't even require the presence of a network connection. I'll take a look at that library to see if it does handle external calls though.